# How entropy increases over time

Tags: space-time, entropy

According to 2nd law of thermodynamic,  in an isolated system entropy increases over tume. In an open system entropy might seems decreases but combined result of all related events results in overall entropy increase.

Now lets say, a suffled deck of playing cards. If I sort the cards it seems entropy decreases, what's then the related  events that increases overall entropy. I am asking just to clear some of my confusions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable for [physics.se].

Comment: [Minute Physics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKbJ9leUNDE&list=PLoaVOjvkzQtyZF-2VpJrxPz7bxK_p1Dd2) did a really good series about entropy a while back. These videos are a good place to start.

Comment: As suggested by @Mick, posted on Physics site for interested audience https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/547297/how-entropy-increases-over-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While more of a physics than astronomy question. Entropy as a whole increase in the universe due to statistical probability. By rearranging a deck of cards looking at the back of them, no matter what order, it is the same macrostate with different arrangements of the cards (microstates). A better example would be if you decreased entropy by picking up cards from the floor and put them together. In that situation, while in your small area the cards lost entropy, you expended energy to do that task. The energy you expend is enough to make the entropy of you and the cards remain constant and arguably increase. However, if you then take into account the entire universe, the rest of it is increasing in entropy at a large rate anyway. This means no matter what you do, entropy will increase overall due to other effects.